# Dropdown not setting value in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have Asp.Net MVC application, I have a dropdown with select, yes and no option. I need values if null is a user chooses select, true if chooses yes and false if the user chooses no. But in my case, it's setting false always.

**CSHTML**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.boolField, new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "YES", Value = "True"},                       
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "NO", Value = "False"}
                    }, "---- Select ----", new { id = "boolField", @class = "form-control" })
```

**Model**

```
public bool? boolField { get; set; }
```

Comment: You probably want to use the BindPropertyAttribute on `public bool? boolField { get; set; }`

Comment: @Lady_A but it's working for other fields without using BindPropertyAttribute

Comment: worst case you try it an it fails. I had this issue before and this is how I solved it